# Refactoring this multi-step form to work with the submit button

Tags: javascript, forms

So I've been working on this snippet for a little while and I'm totally stuck. I'm fairly new to development so I pulled a foundation of this code from Github. I was able to modify it to meet most of my needs.

This is a multi-step form with validation and tooltips for required fields. Essentially, I enable/disable the buttons and tooltips based on the user's interactions.

Everything works as I want except for the last part with the submit button. I want the submit button to be disabled and faded out until the user completes all the fields in step_4 and I've tried a few different things but I can't get the button to fade out to 65% opacity in the background or the tooltips to appear next to the questions if the user tries to hit submit without completing all the questions.

I can upload the html I'm working with but here is a [test site.](https://dashboard.theattributes.com/self-assessment/mental-acuity-testing-script)

This is the two script blocks I'm working with:

```js
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
   // Helper function to enable/disable next button for each step
   
   function enableNextButtonForStep(stepDiv) {
     const buttonNext = stepDiv.querySelector('.button_next');
     const requiredFields = [...stepDiv.querySelectorAll('input[required]')];
     const tooltipButtonAlert = stepDiv.querySelector('.tooltipButtonAlert');
 
     function enableNextButton() {
       console.log(`Inside enableNextButton for ${stepDiv.classList}:`);
       const allFilled = requiredFields.every(field => {
         if (field.type === 'radio' && field.name !== 'Test-Button') {
           const radioGroupName = field.name;
           return stepDiv.querySelector(`input[name="${radioGroupName}"]:checked`);
         } else {
           return field.value.trim() !== '';
         }
       });
 
       if (allFilled) {
         buttonNext.classList.remove('submit-enabled');
         tooltipButtonAlert.style.display = 'none';
       } else {
         buttonNext.classList.add('submit-enabled');
         if (buttonNext.dataset.clicked === "true") {
           tooltipButtonAlert.style.display = 'block';
           console.log('Tooltip should be shown.');
         } else {
           tooltipButtonAlert.style.display = 'none';
           console.log('Tooltip should be hidden.');
         }
       }
 
       console.log(`enableNextButton for ${stepDiv.classList} - allFilled:`, allFilled);
     }
 
     requiredFields.forEach(field => {
       field.addEventListener('input', enableNextButton);
     });
 
     buttonNext.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
       if (buttonNext.classList.contains('submit-enabled')) {
         event.preventDefault();
         buttonNext.dataset.clicked = "true";
         tooltipButtonAlert.style.display = 'block';
         console.log('Button Next is clicked. Tooltip is shown.');
       }
     });
 
     // Initial check
     enableNextButton();
   }
 
   // Get all steps and initialize enableNextButton for each step
   const steps = document.querySelectorAll('.step_1, .step_2, .step_3, .step_4');
   steps.forEach(stepDiv => enableNextButtonForStep(stepDiv));
 };


 // Get the Step 4 element
const step4Div = document.querySelector('.step_4');

if (step4Div) {
    const radioButtons = step4Div.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
    const buttonSubmit = step4Div.querySelector('.button_submit');
    const tooltipButtonAlert = step4Div.querySelector('.tooltipButtonAlert');

    function checkRadioButtons() {
        const allRadioSelected = [...radioButtons].every(radio => radio.checked);
        buttonSubmit.disabled = !allRadioSelected;
        tooltipButtonAlert.style.display = allRadioSelected ? 'none' : 'block';
    }

    radioButtons.forEach(radio => {
        radio.addEventListener('change', checkRadioButtons);
    });

    // Initial check
    checkRadioButtons();
}

 
   </script>
 
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
     const steps = [".step_1", ".step_2", ".step_3", ".step_4"];
     const nextButtons = [".step_1 .button_next", ".step_2 .button_next", ".step_3 .button_next"];
     const prevButtons = [".step_2 .button_previous", ".step_3 .button_previous", ".step_4 .button_previous"];
     let currentStep = 0;
 
     function showStep() {
       steps.forEach((step, index) => {
         if (index === currentStep) {
           $(step).show();
         } else {
           $(step).hide();
         }
       });
     }
 
     function validateStep(step) {
       let isValid = true;
       $(step)
         .find("input[required]")
         .each(function () {
           const input = $(this);
           if (input.is(":radio")) {
             const radioGroupName = input.attr("name");
             if ($(`input[name="${radioGroupName}"]:checked`).length === 0) {
               isValid = false;
               const tooltip = $(`input[name="${radioGroupName}"]`).parent().next(".tooltip");
               if (tooltip.length === 0) {
                 input.parent().after('<div class="tooltip">Please select an option</div>');
               } else {
                 tooltip.show();
               }
             } else {
               const tooltip = input.parent().next(".tooltip");
               if (tooltip.length !== 0) {
                 tooltip.hide();
               }
             }
           } else {
             if (input.val().trim() === "") {
               isValid = false;
               input.css("border", "1px solid red");
               const tooltip = input.next(".tooltip");
               if (tooltip.length === 0) {
                 input.after('<div class="tooltip">This field is required</div>');
               } else {
                 tooltip.show();
               }
             } else {
               input.css("border", "1px solid #f1f1f1");
               input.next(".tooltip").hide();
             }
           }
         });
       return isValid;
     }
 
     function init() {
       showStep();
       nextButtons.forEach((button, index) => {
         $(button).click(() => {
           if (validateStep(steps[index])) {
             currentStep++;
             showStep();
             scrollToTop();
           } else {
             console.log("Validation failed. Cannot proceed.");
           }
         });
       });
 
       prevButtons.forEach((button, index) => {
         $(button).click(() => {
           currentStep--;
           showStep();
           scrollToTop();
         });
       });
 
       $("input").focus(function () {
         $(this).css("border", "1px solid #f1f1f1");
         $(this).next(".tooltip").hide();
       });
     }
 
     function scrollToTop() {
       console.log("Scrolling to the top of the page...");
       $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow", function() {
         console.log("Scrolling complete.");
       });
     }
 
     init();
   });
 </script>
```

I tried variations of this js but I can't get the button to fade out or the tooltips to show on step_4

```
// Get the Step 4 element
const step4Div = document.querySelector('.step_4');

if (step4Div) {
    const radioButtons = step4Div.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
    const buttonSubmit = step4Div.querySelector('.button_submit');
    const tooltipButtonAlert = step4Div.querySelector('.tooltipButtonAlert');

    function checkRadioButtons() {
        const allRadioSelected = [...radioButtons].every(radio => radio.checked);
        buttonSubmit.disabled = !allRadioSelected;
        tooltipButtonAlert.style.display = allRadioSelected ? 'none' : 'block';
    }

    radioButtons.forEach(radio => {
        radio.addEventListener('change', checkRadioButtons);
    });

    // Initial check
    checkRadioButtons();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is useful, but this is what I had on top of my head. Using the fieldset for showing/hiding because it has some build in features like getting the list of elements in the fieldset.

Maybe the CSS can be optimized. I haven't time, so if you have any ideas please comment.

### Update

I added a check for the validity of the entire form when the input event happens. Based on that the submit button will be enabled.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('input', e => {
  let fieldset = e.target.closest('fieldset');
  let form = e.target.form;
  // get the number of invalid form fields
  let invalid = [...fieldset.elements].filter(elm => !elm.validity.valid).length;
  // set disabled equal to the number (0=false, 0>true)
  fieldset.elements.next.disabled = invalid;
  // enable submit button when all are valid
  let forminvalid = form.checkValidity();
  form.submitbutton.disabled = !forminvalid;
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = new FormData(e.target);
  console.log([...data]);
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let fieldset = e.target.closest('fieldset');
  let form = e.target.form;
  // set form[data-fieldset] based on the button clicked
  switch(e.target.name){
    case 'next':
      form.dataset.fieldset = fieldset.dataset.next;
      break;
    case 'prev':
      form.dataset.fieldset = fieldset.dataset.prev;
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
form.form fieldset {
  display: none;
}

form[data-fieldset="f1"] fieldset[name="f1"] {
  display: block;
}

form[data-fieldset="f2"] fieldset[name="f2"] {
  display: block;
}

form[data-fieldset="f3"] fieldset[name="f3"] {
  display: block;
}

button {
  background-color: PaleGreen;
  color: black;
  border-radius: .3em;
  transition: all 1s;
}

button:disabled {
  background-color: DarkSalmon;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01" data-fieldset="f1" class="form">
  <fieldset name="f1" data-next="f2">
    <p>I am aware when an unsafe situation is about to arise</p>
    <label>
      <span>Never</span>
      <input type="radio" name="safe" value="0" required>
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Always</span>
      <input type="radio" name="safe" value="6">
    </label>
    <p>I stay in the moment</p>
    <label>
      <span>Never</span>
      <input type="radio" name="moment" value="0" required>
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Always</span>
      <input type="radio" name="moment" value="6">
    </label>
    <label>
    <button name="next" type="button" disabled>Next</button>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name="f2" data-next="f3" data-prev="f1">
    <p>I easily move on from mistakes</p>
    <label>
      <span>Never</span>
      <input type="radio" name="mistake" value="0" required>
    </label>
    <label>
      <span>Always</span>
      <input type="radio" name="mistake" value="6">
    </label>
    <label>
    <button name="next" type="button" disabled>Next</button>
    <button name="prev" type="button">prev</button>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset name="f3" data-prev="f2">
    <p>Submit</p>
    <button name="prev" type="button">prev</button>
    <label>
    <button type="submit" name="submitbutton" disabled>Submit</button>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Hey @chrwahl, 

Thank you for the response. I was playing around with what you wrote and the next functionality on F1 and F2 work great. 

My problem is what to do with the submit button. The f3 section is really where I'm stuck because I can't make the button fade out. Any thoughts on how to make the submit button fade until there are all questions answered?

Comment: @NicholasGrahamPlatt I updated my answer. Now, that you write "fade out" I hope that it is ok that this is archived using the disable functionality of the buttons. This is how it should be done -- build in functionality is always preferred.

Comment: I also added a transition to the style of the buttons.